# Prevent date_modified changes when reducing stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have written a script that, among other things, shows me how many days ago a product was updated/modified. Everything works perfectly, however it has become evident to me that `get_date_modified()` is returning the date/time of the last time the product was ordered.

I have a custom script that is reducing stock based on an attribute. I believe this is the culprit. I would like `date_modified` not to update on stock change via purchase, only when the product is manually updated.

How can I bypass the updating of `date_modified` when this function fires? Is there a filter that can be utilized perhaps?

Stock reduction code:

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// --------------------------  REDUCE WEIGHT BASED ON WEIGHT FIELD  ----------------------- //
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// reduce stock based on 'pa_weight' attribute
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity', 'filter_order_item_quantity', 10, 3 ); 
function filter_order_item_quantity( $quantity, $order, $item )  
{
    $product   = $item->get_product();
    $term_name = $product->get_attribute('pa_weight');

    // 'pa_weight' - keep only the numbers
    $quantity = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $term_name);

    // new quantity
    if( is_numeric ( $quantity ) && $quantity != 0 )
        $quantity *= $quantity;

    return $quantity;
}


/**
 * Order change stock reduction fix.
 * 
 * @param $prevent
 * @param $item
 * @param $item_quantity
 * @return bool|mixed
 */
function custom_stock_reduction_order_change( $prevent, $item, $item_quantity ) {
    $stock_reduced   = wc_stock_amount( $item->get_meta( '_reduced_stock', true ) );
    $stock_reduction = filter_order_item_quantity( $item->get_quantity(), null, $item );

    if ( $stock_reduction == $stock_reduced ) {
        $prevent = true;
    }

    return $prevent;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_prevent_adjust_line_item_product_stock', 'custom_stock_reduction_order_change', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: `$item->update_meta_data( '_reduced_stock', $item_quantity - $restock_refunded_items );
 $item->save();` This is executing inside the reduce stock function. Whenever a save is called, the modified date will get updated. You may just need to update the meta directly in the snippet and return false to the callback.

Comment: @mujuonly thanks for this. Are you able to elaborate a bit more? So my first function is simply filtering the amount and allowing the system to complete the update - whereas you are suggesting I bypass the general Woocommerce code and update the meta myself?